# Counter to count items' occurrence in several lists and return tuple (item, count in list 1, count in list 2)

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, nltk

I am working on the kaggle 'what's cooking' competition and I want to improve the counting of different ingredients. I realised it's silly to  treat raw strings like 'ground black pepper' and 'black pepper' differently, so I want to compare 2 lists.

1. the original/raw list with arbitrarily long ingredient string like 'ground black pepper'
2. processed ingredient list where all >= 3 word ingredient string are converted into lists of bigrams with 'ground black' and 'black pepper'

after processing and preparing list (I ran a bigram generator for all ingredient phrases with 3 or more words), I ran a Counter function and I now have a list of tuples of the form ('ingredient string', count) for each list (raw and processed). I want to make a dataframe, where

ingredient   | count in raw | count in processed | difference

salt         |       15550  |              15000 | 0

black pepper |       13000  |              15235 | 2235

...

Is there a Counter object, that can efficiently (preferrably O(n)) count occurrence of item like string in 2 lists.

here is my code:

```
with open('data/train.json', 'r') as f:
    train_json = f.read()

stop = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)

trainset = json.loads(train_json)
# read the data in and export the ingredient column into a list
df = pd.read_json('data/train.json')
all_recipes = df.ingredients.tolist()

# extract all ingridents from all cuisines into one flat list
all_ingr_raw = [ingr.lower() for recipe in all_recipes for ingr in recipe]

# compare 2 lists for most common ingredients - raw unprocessed ingredients vs processed, where
# processed is a 1-2 word ingredients or ngrams of >=3 word ingredients

# take all ingredient strings that have more than 2 whitespaces in them i.e. 3 words
three_word_ingr = [ingr for ingr in all_ingr_raw if len(ingr.split()) > 2]

# make a list of sublists of bigram tuples for each string from above 
raw_three_word_ngrams = [list(ngrams(phrase.split(),2)) for phrase in three_word_ingr]
# turn tuples into strings and flatten the list
proc_three_word_ngrams = [' '.join(pair) for sublist in raw_three_word_ngrams for pair in sublist]
# join all ingredient strings of 2 words or less with the flat list of all bigrams out of >3 word strings
all_ingr_ngrams = [ingr for ingr in all_ingr_raw if len(ingr.split()) <= 2] + proc_three_word_ngrams

# return a sorted (descending in count) set of tuples (ingredient, count)
count_ingr_raw = Counter(all_ingr_raw).most_common()   
count_ingr_ngrams = Counter(all_ingr_ngrams).most_common()

common = [x for x in count_ingr_raw if x[0] in count_ingr_ngrams]
unique_raw = [x for x in count_ingr_raw if x[0] not in count_ingr_ngrams]
unique_proc = [x for x in count_ingr_ngrams if x[0] not in count_ingr_raw]

# find 
print common[:20]
print unique_raw[:20]
print unique_proc[:20]

[]
[(u'salt', 18049), (u'olive oil', 7972), (u'onions', 7972), (u'water', 7457), (u'garlic', 7380), (u'sugar', 6434), (u'garlic cloves', 6237), (u'butter', 4848), (u'ground black pepper', 4785), (u'all-purpose flour', 4632), (u'pepper', 4438), (u'vegetable oil', 4385), (u'eggs', 3388), (u'soy sauce', 3296), (u'kosher salt', 3113), (u'green onions', 3078), (u'tomatoes', 3058), (u'large eggs', 2948), (u'carrots', 2814), (u'unsalted butter', 2782)]
[(u'salt', 18049), (u'olive oil', 10916), (u'black pepper', 8039), (u'onions', 7972), (u'water', 7457), (u'garlic', 7380), (u'garlic cloves', 7110), (u'sugar', 6434), (u'ground black', 5004), (u'butter', 4848), (u'soy sauce', 4822), (u'vegetable oil', 4731), (u'all-purpose flour', 4632), (u'pepper', 4438), (u'bell pepper', 4190), (u'green onions', 3550), (u'eggs', 3388), (u'chicken broth', 3386), (u'kosher salt', 3179), (u'red pepper', 3169)]
```

Comment: Put the ngrams into the dataframe first then query the dataframe. Instead of processing the ngrams then putting them into the dataframe.

Comment: Could you post your json file or  a sample of your json somewhere? Then, it's easier to help you.